# Deadlock while sending data to channel in slice of channels

Tags: go, slice, channel

**Sending data to integer channel in slice of channels is resulting into deadlock**

The code is expected to create 5 (+1 `fanInChan`) channels. These channels are used for send integer values through `send()` and receive the same in `receive()` and finally Fan-in the them to `fanInChan`.

Code:-

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("About to exit!")
    fmt.Println("Started")

    channels := make([]chan int, 5)
    fanInChan := make(chan int)

    go send(channels)
    go recive(fanInChan, channels)

    for val := range fanInChan {
        fmt.Println("Fanin", val)
    }
}
func send(channels []chan int) {
    defer fmt.Println("Send Ended")
    fmt.Println("Send Started")

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        channels[i%5] <- i
    }

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        close(channels[i])
    }
}

func recive(fanin chan<- int, channels []chan int) {
    defer fmt.Println("Recive Ended")
    fmt.Println("Recive Started")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(5)

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func(inew int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println(inew)
            for v := range channels[inew] {
                fanin <- v
            }
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(fanin)
}
```

[Golang PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/zetCh6-u9QC)

OutPut:-

```
Started
Send Started
Recive Started
4
1
2
3
0
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
... //You can see rest on playground link above
```

Problem is starting in a for loop inside `send()`

```
for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        channels[i%5] <- i
    }
```

Comment: The values are supposed to receive in `receive()` in the channels created by goroutines in for loop

Comment: In `receive()`, each goroutine is ranging over a separate channel `channel[0] to channel[4]` which is supposed to send the integer value to `fanin`. Those values will be recived in `main()` on channel `fanInChan`.

Comment: oops, my bad, I read the code wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `channels := make([]chan int, 5)` is allocating a array with nil channels which

- Blocks receiving `<- channel` from channel
- Blocks sending `channel <- value` into channel
- panics on closing `close(channel)`

So you have to initialize each channel individually to recive integer values.

You should init the channels in the `channels` array before using those.

```
    for i := range channels {
        channels[i] = make(chan int)
    }
```

Insert this just before the line `go send(channels)` and run.